# In Cassandra: How to limit results of list-column in selects

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

In relational databases we make many-to-many relations by using junction tables, but on the Cassandra what is best practice for storing many-to-many relations in form that we can limit relation results of rows, suppose we have a "Tweets" table and i want store "Like" events of users, every like row is a **User Defined Type** by below describe:

```
CREATE TYPE social.likes (
    liker_user_id int,
    action_time timestamp;
);
```

And Tweets table described as below:

```
CREATE TABLE social.tweets (
    owner_id bigint,
    id uuid,
    "_short_content" text,
    comments list<frozen<likes>>,
    content text,
    created_time timestamp,
    image text,
    images text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    PRIMARY KEY (owner_id, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Now suppose in social project we have a tweets by ten million likes, how can i get this tweets only by last ten users that liked this tweets by using CQL?